# react-native application shows white screen after forced reboot via codePush.restartApp

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

I force restart react native application after installing code push update using codePush.restartApp(true). At the moment of restart, a white screen appears for a second and then the splash screen from react-native-bootsplash is shown. Please tell me how to get rid of this white screen

Here is the reboot initialization and codePush configuration

```
if (intervalId) {
      return clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
    const codePushSyncCallback = (status: codePush.SyncStatus) => {
      switch (status) {
        case codePush.SyncStatus.CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE: {
          rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowProgressBar(false)
          rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateStatus(status);
          setStatus(status);
          break;
        }
        case codePush.SyncStatus.UP_TO_DATE: {
          rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowProgressBar(false)
          rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateStatus(status)
          setStatus(status)
          rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateProgress(50)

          intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            if (rootStore.userStorage.updateProgress === 100) {
              if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                await changeNavigationBarColor(WHITE, true, true)
              }
              rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowUpdateProgress(false)
              return
            }
            rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateProgress(rootStore.userStorage.updateProgress + 10)
          }, 500)
          break;
        }
        case codePush.SyncStatus.DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE: {
          rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowProgressBar(true)
          rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowUpdateProgress(true)
          rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateStatus(status);
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            changeNavigationBarColor(CUSTOM_BLUE, true, true)
          }
          setStatus(status);
          break;
        }
        case codePush.SyncStatus.INSTALLING_UPDATE: {
          rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateStatus(status);
          setStatus(status);
          break;
        }
        case codePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED: {
          rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateStatus(status);
          setStatus(status);
          rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowProgressBar(false)
          rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowUpdateProgress(false)
          **codePush.allowRestart();
          codePush.restartApp(true);**
          break;
        }
        case codePush.SyncStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR: {
          rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowProgressBar(false)
          rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateStatus(status);
          rootStore.userStorage.setIsShowUpdateProgress(false)
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            changeNavigationBarColor(CUSTOM_BLUE, true, true)
          }
          setStatus(status);
          break;
        }
        default: {
          break
        }
      }
    }

    **codePush.sync**(
      codePushOptions,
      codePushSyncCallback,
      (progress) => {
        const percentage = Math.floor((progress.receivedBytes / progress.totalBytes) * 100)
        rootStore.userStorage.setUpdateProgress(percentage)
        setProgress(percentage)
      }
    )
```

Comment: same here, was trying to solve it for 4 days, didn't find any fix on the internet yet, did you?
btw even when you enter the app, evertime after you downloaded the codepush update, you will see that white screen again and again.